# Golang CircleCI 2.0 test failing with signal: killed

Tags: go, circleci-2.0

I am migrating to circleci2.0 and after successful build when tests are executed they are randomly failing with following error messages

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: flushing $WORK/b462/payment_step_svc.test: write $WORK/b462/svc.test: cannot allocate memory
```

I used the following config

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:latest
      - image: rabbitmq:3.5.4
      - image: redis

    working_directory: /go/src/github.com/soniabhishek/taskrunner

    environment:
      GOOS: linux
      GOARCH: amd64
      GOPATH: /go

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Get dependencies
          command: go get -t -d -v ./...
      - run:
          name: Build all
          command: go build ./...
      - run:
          name: Test all
          command: go test -v ./...
```

I have tried for many golang versions other than latest like (1.10.3).

Although I found the **hack** for this but I am not sure why is this happening,
all my tests run when I use ***CGO_ENABLED=0***

Would like to know why is this issue occurring and permanent solution for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two clues here that suggest you are consuming too much memory, and the OS is forcibly killing your "rogue" process. They are:

> killed
>
> cannot allocate memory

You can confirm this by getting an SSH session at the end of a failed build, and examining the kill history using `dmesg`. If it gives you a ["sacrifice child"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282155/what-is-the-out-of-memory-message-sacrifice-child) message, then you hit a memory limit so severe that the OS was forced to remove a process from memory.

You have several options. I put them here in the order I would suggest you prefer them:

- Reduce your memory consumption by making changes to your Go program
- Ask CircleCI to set you up with a larger Docker container (this will be a chargeable option). The default is 4G, I believe 8G and 16G are available
- Swap to a Machine executor (presently free of charge, subject to change). This gives you 8G of RAM, but you lose some of the flexibility of the Docker approach (e.g. you have to use one of a few preset base images).

Comment: `dmesg` does not work on docker images in CircleCI. Unless you found a way to make it work?…

Comment: @Sardathrion: thanks for the note. You are quite right, I tried `dmesg` just now in an Alpine container. Would I be right in thinking that an individual process within a container would be `kill`ed (by the host or by Docker) in the case of that task exceeding the container's memory limit?

Comment: I don't recall the my information I used in relation to this answer, but any CI environment will bump into this problem in some fashion, regardless of whether they are Dockerised. I expect that a "killed" OS message should be available from somewhere - could this maybe be run on the host, and still be reasonably detailed about what was killed in a container?

Comment: (Thinking about it, I think container level processes should be individually killable by the host, since "containers don't exist" - they are just an illusion set up by a number of processes sharing the same cgroup. But I would be interested to hear your thoughts).

Comment: Based on my little imperfect experience, using some `sleep` statement had the effect of allowing the build to pass *sometimes*. I can build the code just fine (using the same commands) on a toy VM with much less capacity as "normal" so thought that adding `sleep` would help. However, this create a horrid Heisenbug that is not worth it. I am now paying for CircleCI and move to "xlarge" machines and the problem has vanished.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in this situation was `go test -p 1` to tell Go to run just one compilation at a time.

Without that Go will run the number of CPUs you have, which by default on CircleCI is two.